# Java 120 char ECDSA public key to 130 char or Ethereum address

Tags: java, ethereum, web3-java

I am given a 120 char ECDSA generated X509 public key by an external system. I now want to use it in Ethereum by converting it to an address.

(not the real key but an example of the content (120 chars)) 
**`MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EE123456789n9DSxZh3wfq0BIL5LDF5B54e07bxFiKc89K/GaKj4qrGC/Mb/KnakQBrN4khMQHLnxm7TjaxXQPxtJMV5b+A==`**

I can't see an easy way of doing this with web3j, perhaps there is another way?
I think, looking at the tests, `org.web3j.crypto.Keys.getAddress(String)` expects the 130 character hex version.

How do I convert the **120 chars** to a **130 char** hex representation to allow me to call the getAddress method or maybe there is a direct way of converting the 120 char pub key to Ethereum address?

Comment: Your 120 chars are apparently BASE64 coded; they represent 90 bytes, which would be represented as 180 characters in hex. Too much to get to 130 hex chars.

Comment: think something else has to happen first. Some sort of conversion on it.

Comment: Start with decoding the base64-encoded string and check the length of the resulting byte array (your example actually does not decode correctly; with one more char, it would decode to 88 bytes). If the resulting length is 65, you probably just have to hex-encode it. If not, it's not really suitable to become a 130 char hex string without adding or losing information.

Comment: ok so I get 88 bytes, when I decoded the actual key using Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey).length.   So I guess its not suitable for an Ethererum address?

Comment: According to the internets, you have to calculate a Keccak-256 hash of your public key, then take the rightmost 20 bytes of the hash and encode them as a hexadecimal string. Or so. Please double-check, I am not compentent in all that cryptocurrency stuff and I do not want you to accidentally send virtual money to a non-existant address, thus destroying it forever.

Comment: Yeah, so Web3j will do that bit for me.  But the tricky part is getting the X509 ECDSA key into something meaningful. I have no idea why its 88 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a valid Base64 encoded SECP-256k1 public key, the following code would enable you to get the Ethereum address using Web3j.

```
String encodedKey = "MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EE123456789n9DSxZh3wfq0BIL5LDF5B54e07bxFiKc89K/GaKj4qrGC/Mb/KnakQBrN4khMQHLnxm7TjaxXQPxtJMV5b+A==";
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
String address = Keys.getAddress(Numeric.toHexString(decoded));
```

However, as mentioned in the comments, it appears that the input encoded key is not a 128 bit public key, but an X.509 cert. Hence you'll need to do something along these lines:

```
String encodedKey = "MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EE123456789n9DSxZh3wfq0BIL5LDF5B54e07bxFiKc89K/GaKj4qrGC/Mb/KnakQBrN4khMQHLnxm7TjaxXQPxtJMV5b+A==";

byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);

CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));

// TODO: Figure out how to convert this PublicKey into a byte array or BigInteger
byte[] publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();

String address = Keys.getAddress(Hex.toHexString(publicKey));
```

It's also worth mentioning that the OpenSSL command line tool can be very helpful too for converting certificates into different formats.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely an 88-byte value is a certificate; it is much more likely the SubjectPublicKeyInfo _part_ of a certificate as defined by X.509 and more conveniently available in rfc5280 4.1. This is what Java calls `X509EncodedKeySpec` (see the javadoc for `java.security.Key`) and OpenSSL calls `PUBKEY`. It has an outer DER SEQUENCE and (for EC) another SEQUENCE of two OIDs and a BIT STRING 'wrapper' prefixing the actual public-point value.

Comment: This example isn't a valid base 64 encoding either

Comment: The Q makes clear that the posted value was mangled to hide the true value -- by someone who doesn't understand and know how to preserve correct base64 format. But OP says in comment that decoding 'the actual key' is 88 bytes. And a _valid_ 120-char base64 ending with == would indeed decode to 88 bytes.